# Django ./manage.py

Tags: python, django

I was wondering how to set up a configuration file on my computer so that when I want to run manage.py for my django project I would be able to run "./manage.py" as opposed to "python manage.py".

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you're on Windows, you can already provided the file extension registration is correct (invoking `python.exe` rather than `pythonw.exe`, I mean, or you won't see the console output and it won't wait for it to finish).

On other operating systems, make `manage.py` executable with `chmod +x manage.py` and then you can do `./manage.py`. It should have the `#!/usr/bin/env python` hashbang already which tells it what program to run it with.

(This applies to everything, not just `manage.py` - read about the shebang ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29)) for more info.)

Answer (score 7):

```
chmod +x manage.py
```

should do it

Answer (score 0):

On Linux/OSX, I:

```
sudo chmod 777 ./manage.py
```

After that, I can run it without specifying python. Hope that helps you out.